# Determine whether sequence of independent rvs satisfy SLLN

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Determine if the following sequences of independent rvs satisfy the SLLN:
>
> - $(a)$ $P(X_n=1) = \frac{1}{n^2},\, P(X_n=0) = 1-\frac{1}{n^2}$
> - $(b)$ $P(X_n=n) = \frac{1}{n^2},\, P(X_n=0) = 1-\frac{1}{n^2}$
> - $(c)$ $P(X_n=n) = \frac{1}{n}, \, P(X_n=0) = 1-\frac{1}{n}$

**My attempt:** Let $S_n = X_1 + X_2+\ldots + X_n$.

- $(a)$: $E(X_n) = \frac{1}{n^2} = E(X_n^2)$.  We need to verify: $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n - E(S_n)}{n}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely. Now, $E(S_n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2}$, so as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $E(S_n)\rightarrow \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, which implies $\frac{E(S_n)}{n}\rightarrow 0$. However, $S_n\leq n$ for every $n$, thus as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{S_n}{n} = \frac{n-k}{n} \rightarrow 1$, unless all $X_i$'s $=0$ (which is an extreme case, since $X_n$ are random). Thus $X_n$ does **not** satisfy SLLN.
- $(b)$: $E(X_n) = \frac{1}{n}$ and $E(X_n^2) = 1$. Thus $E(S_n)$ diverges as $n\rightarrow \infty$, while $S_n = kn$ for some nonnegative integers $k$. Thus, we could apply the L'Hospital rule (variable is $n$) to compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n - E(S_n)}{n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2}) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\neq 0$, so $X_n$ does **not** satisfy SLLN.
- $(c)$: $E(X_n) = 1$, so $E(S_n)=  n$. Thus, $S_n - E(S_n) = (k-1)n$ for some nonnegative integers $k$. Thus, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n - E(S_n)}{n} = k-1 = 0$ if and only if $k=1$. So, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n - E(S_n)}{n}$ does not converge to $0$ almost surely (**is this correct**?). Thus, $X_n$ does **not** satisfy SLLN.

**My question:** I'm quite skeptical with my solution above since the way I tried to express $S_n$ seems to be weird. Could anyone please help me with these problems in case my solutions above are incorrect? Any thoughts would really be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: In (a), what can you say about the random set of indices $n$ such that $X_n\ne0$?

Comment: Their sum equals to $n$. That is why I have $S_n = n-k$, where $k$ stands for all variables $X_j, \ldots, X_{j+k-1}$ equal to $0$.

Comment: "Their sum equals to n" What? The sum of the indices $n$ such that $X_n\ne0$ is equal to $n$? No idea what you mean here.

Comment: Is $P(\{ n : X_n=1 \} \text{ is infinite})$ positive in a? You may want to think about Borel-Cantelli...

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking sir:P The random set of indices $n$ should be all natural numbers except $0$.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, it does. Because it's the partial sum of a divergent series (harmonic series with $p=1$), so $P(n: X_n=1 i.o) > 0$. So it really means $S_n\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. But then what could we say about $\frac{S_n}{n}$?

Comment: What harmonic series? I was looking at $a$, not $c$.

Comment: Hmmm... my impression is that at this point you need to reread very slowly the words: `the random set of indices n such that Xn≠0` and understand what they mean. Stating that "The random set of indices n should be all natural numbers except 0" simply shows you did not think this through carefully enough.

Comment: @Ian and Did: nevermind, I messed up. $P(n: X_n = 1\ \text{i.o}) = 0$ since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(n: X_n = 1) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} < \infty$. Thus, $S_n$ converges to some constant $k$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. So part (a)'s correct answer is actually "satisfying SLNN." Same with part (b), with exactly the same argument. But how about part (c), when we could use Borel-Cantelli to conclude that $P(n: X_n = n\ \text{i.o}) > 0$, which means $S_n\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: See what my friend. In (a), where you say that $S_{n}= n-k$, you really should have said that $S_{n} = n-k(n)$. Here $k$ depends on $n$. And thus you can't trivially say that $\frac{S_{n}}{n} \to 1$. You should think over how $k$ depends on $n$.

Comment: @kolobokish: that's right! I think I was able to show that (a) and (b) satisfy SLLN in the comment right above yours. The key is using Borel-Cantelli lemma. Is it correct? But then for part (c), $S_n\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, so could you help with part (c)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but here is some comment. $P(X_{1}=1) =1$, so your $k \geq 1$. Now let's find the measure of set of $\omega$-s, for which $k=1$. This can be only in the case where all other random variables take 0 value. Being independent the measure would be $\prod_{i=2}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n}) = \lim \frac{1}{n} = 0 $. That means the expression does not converge almost everywhere.

Comment: why the product is from $2$ to $\infty$? And why that's the measure of $w$?

Comment: I'm not a fan of probabilities , I'm sorry. Speaking just from the view of measure theory.)) About $2$. We should look for 0-s in the other random variables, as we know that the first one is almost surely non 0. (literally i mean that if we multiply from 1, we will for sure have 0.). Never mind about $\omega$. I mean we should have find the probability(summed up) of the cases, for which the $k=1$. That's only for the case where starting from the second random variable all the variables take value 0.

Comment: @Ian: were you able to solve part (c)? I tried your hint, but I got $S_n\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$...

Comment: @user177196 The idea for (c) is that at each time $n$ such that $X_n=n$, the sequence $\frac{S_n}n$ "jumps" by nearly $+1$,and that these jumps prevent it to converge to any finite limit. More rigorously, assume that $$\frac{S_n}n\to L$$ almost surely, for some random almost surely finite $L$, then $$\frac{X_n}n=\frac{S_n}n-\frac{S_{n-1}}{n-1}\frac{n}{n-1}\to L-L=0$$ almost surely, which is impossible since $X_n=n$ infinitely many times hence $$P\left(\limsup \frac{X_n}n=1\right)=1$$ Note that this argument requires that $L-L=0$, that is, that $L$ is finite.

Comment: @Did: Thank you so much for your help. But I think you made a minor mistake: the coefficient of $S_{n-1}/(n-1)$ should be $\frac{n-1}{n}$.

Comment: @user177196 Definitely. Well spotted.

Comment: It seems that you upvoted Did's comment, but this is only Borel-Cantelli. $P(\lim\sup \frac {X_n}{n}=1)=1$ is Borel-Cantelli. $\lim\sup X_n$ can be equal to $\infty$, but as correctly commented below my answer, this does not imply that $X_n$ is not Cesaro-summable. Moreover, the statement $L-L=0$ implies/requires that $L$ is finite, is not correct (except if I misunderstood it).

Comment: @JimmyR. "the statement L−L=0 implies/requires that L is finite, is not correct (except if I misunderstood it)" Yes, if you think this is not correct, either you lack the basics of the subject or indeed you misunderstood it. Either way, I would appreciate if you could stop critiquing the comments I post on the site without addressing your critics at the author of these comments, that is, me. Or are you trying to avoid that I read your critiques? For example, in your last comment, the assertion that "this is only Borel-Cantelli" is squarely wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The SLLN by Kolmogorov for independent sequence $\left(X_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, states that if

1. $Var(X_n)<\infty, \mathbb E[X_n]=μ_n$ for every $n$,
2. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{Var(X_n)}{n^2}<\infty$

then $\frac1n(S_n-\mathbb ES_n)\overset{a.s.}\longrightarrow 0$. These are *sufficient* but not *necessary* meaning, that every sequence that satisfies these (actually the second is the one to check) satisfies the SLLN, but if a sequence does not satisfy these, then this does not mean that it cannot satisfy the SLLN.

So, in your case:

- $(a)$: $\mathrm{Var}[X_n]\le \mathbb E[X_n^2]=\frac1{n^2}$ and so $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{Var(X_n)}{n^2}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^4}<\infty$$
  and so, it *does* satisfy the SLLN.
- $(b)$: $\mathrm{Var}[X_n]\le \mathbb E[X_n^2]=1$ and so, as in $(a)$ 
  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{Var(X_n)}{n^2}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}<\infty$$
  and so, it *does* satisfy the SLLN.
- $(c)$: Here $Var(X_n)=n-1$, hence $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{Var(X_n)}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n-1}{n^2}=\infty$$
  and so, this way does not work! (But as mentioned above, it does not mean that we are done). However, if we consider the independent events $E_n:\{ω:X_n(ω)=n\}$, we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(E_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n=\infty$$ and hence by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma: $$P(\lim\sup_nE_n)=P(X_n=n \text{ occurs i.o.})=1$$ This, however, still does not allow you to show that \begin{align}P\left(\lim_{n}\frac{S_n-\mathbb E[S_n]}{n}\neq 0\right)&=P\left(\lim_{n}\frac{S_n}{n}\neq 1\right)\\[0.2cm]&\ge P\left(\lim_{n}\frac{S_n}{n}> 1\right)= P\left(\lim\sup E_n\right)=1\end{align}
  since there are unbounded sequences that are cesaro-summable.

Comment: Re (c), why $$P\left(\lim_{n}\frac{S_n}{n}> 1\right)= P\left(\lim\sup \{X_n=n\}\right)\ ?$$ Note that there exists some sequences $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\in\{0,n\}$ for every $n$ and $x_n=n$ infinitely often and $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k\to1$, so you really need to explain what happens here.

Comment: Re (a) and (b), you use a large hammer to solve elementary questions, as shown in the comments on main and as the OP themselves realized).

Comment: @user177196 Thanks for accepting my answer, but what about c)? Did you solve it?

Comment: @JimmyR.: I used Did's help, as it's a bit slicker.